# Save and Load axes in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, save, load, matlab-guide, axes

I have a Matlab GUI same bellow:
[image]

I want to save axes1 when click on save button, and load one saved axes in this axes1 position when click load button.
How can i do it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to save the data that is plotted in the axes? If so, do you want to save it in `.mat` format or does it have to be a `.csv` file? etc.. You also need to provide information about the type of the data and how you plot it at the moment. Including some code would also be helpful.. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is a [`save`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function in matlab, as well as a [`load`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) function.

Comment: @Vahe Tshitoyan, I want to plot "Travelling Salesman Problem" in it. and i don't now which format is better for save it.

Comment: I would recommend watching a few tutorials, e.g. [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html) followed by something like [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/reading-excel-data-into-matlab-with-a-gui-part-1-98224.html). Your question is too broad.